# How to add More that one webview to two XML file

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java programing language.
In my app I have two side menus (left menu and right menu). And I have a `WebView` in my app which loads my Website home page.

But the issue is that I am unable to add another webwiew to my left and right menus.

Whenever I try to update or add to my menu.XML I always get the error

> unfortunate App has stopped

My AiDE does not show any error.

How can I add more webwiews to different XML files with just on `MainActivity.java` file?

Comment: Are you talking about Android?

Comment: Yes I just go through my codes again and found where am making error. Problem solved.